# JS filters brake the cards structure and positioning

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, card

I have some basic JS written down so i can make some filters for the cards i have created, but using them totally breaks the cards for some reason, both in positioning AND structure. It removes what i guess is some padding and for some reason it skips columns in bootstrap. Here is the php file for the cards, the code and the JS ive written!

What the look like before: [image: before]

What they look like after using the filters/buttons: [image: after]

```
<?php
  $karti = [
    ['karta' => 'Име на проектот стои овде во две линии', 'klasa' => 'програмирање'],
    ['karta' => 'Име на проектот стои овде во две линии', 'klasa' => 'програмирање'],
    ['karta' => 'Име на проектот стои овде во две линии', 'klasa' => 'програмирање'],
    ['karta' => 'Име на проектот стои овде во две линии', 'klasa' => 'програмирање'],
    ['karta' => 'Име на проектот стои овде во две линии', 'klasa' => 'програмирање'],
    ['karta' => 'Име на проектот стои овде во две линии', 'klasa' => 'програмирање'],
    ['karta' => 'Име на проектот стои овде во две линии', 'klasa' => 'програмирање'],
    ['karta' => 'Име на проектот стои овде во две линии', 'klasa' => 'програмирање'],
    ['karta' => 'Име на проектот стои овде во две линии', 'klasa' => 'програмирање'],
    ['karta' => 'Име на проектот стои овде во две линии', 'klasa' => 'програмирање'],
    ['karta' => 'Име на проектот стои овде во две линии', 'klasa' => 'маркетинг'],
    ['karta' => 'Име на проектот стои овде во две линии', 'klasa' => 'маркетинг'],
    ['karta' => 'Име на проектот стои овде во две линии', 'klasa' => 'маркетинг'],
    ['karta' => 'Име на проектот стои овде во две линии', 'klasa' => 'маркетинг'],
    ['karta' => 'Име на проектот стои овде во две линии', 'klasa' => 'маркетинг'],
    ['karta' => 'Име на проектот стои овде во две линии', 'klasa' => 'маркетинг'],
    ['karta' => 'Име на проектот стои овде во две линии', 'klasa' => 'дизајн'],
    ['karta' => 'Име на проектот стои овде во две линии', 'klasa' => 'дизајн'],
    ['karta' => 'Име на проектот стои овде во две линии', 'klasa' => 'дизајн'],
    ['karta' => 'Име на проектот стои овде во две линии', 'klasa' => 'дизајн']
];


function displayrandomphoto() {
    $photos = array("photos/1.jpg", "photos/2.jpg", "photos/3.jpg", "photos/4.jpg", "photos/5.jpg", "photos/6.jpg", "photos/7.jpg", "photos/8.jpg", "photos/9.jpg", "photos/10.jpg");
    $nekojsl = array_rand($photos);
    $randomslika = $photos[$nekojsl];
    echo "<img src=\"$randomslika\" alt=\"projpic\" class=\"card-img-top mb-3\">";
}


?>

<div class="row nav-bg">
    <div class="col-8 offset-2">
    <div class="row cards-list">
  <?php
    foreach ($karti as $card) : ?>
        <div class='col-4 mb-3'>
            <div class='brad'><a href="#" target="_blank">
                <div class="smaller p-0 card <?php echo $card['klasa'] ?> h-100 zoom" data-category="<?php echo $card['klasa']?>">
                    
                    <div class='card-body'>
                        <?php echo displayrandomphoto() ?>
                        <span class='card-text' style='background-color:#fcd232;color:#302f38; padding:2%; font-size:10px;'>
                            Академија за <?php echo $card['klasa'] ?>
                        </span>
                        <h5 class='mt-2 card-title'><b><?php echo $card['karta'] ?></b></h5>
                        <p class='mb-3 mt-1 sss card-text' style='font-size:11px'>
                            Краток опис во кој студентите ќе можат да опишат за што се работи во проектот.
                        </p>
                        <p style='font-size:9px;' class='mb-2 card-text'><b>Winter 2021</b></p>
                        <a href='#' class='btn btn-danger tntt rounded desno' target='_blank' style='font-size:10px;'>Дознај повеќе</a></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div></div></div>

    $('#programiranjeBtn').click(function() {
    var divsToHideMarketing = document.getElementsByClassName("маркетинг");
    for(var i = 0; i < divsToHideMarketing.length; i++){
        divsToHideMarketing[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    divsToHideItn = document.getElementsByClassName("дизајн");
    for(var i = 0; i < divsToHideItn.length; i++){
        divsToHideItn[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    
    var divsToShow = document.getElementsByClassName("програмирање");
    for(var i = 0; i < divsToShow.length; i++){
        divsToShow[i].style.display = "block";
    }
});

$('#marketingBtn').click(function() {
    var divsToShowMarketing = document.getElementsByClassName("маркетинг");
    for(var i = 0; i < divsToShowMarketing.length; i++){
        divsToShowMarketing[i].style.display = "block";
    }
    divsToHideItn = document.getElementsByClassName("дизајн");
    for(var i = 0; i < divsToHideItn.length; i++){
        divsToHideItn[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    
    var divsToHideProgramiranje = document.getElementsByClassName("програмирање");
    for(var i = 0; i < divsToHideProgramiranje.length; i++){
        divsToHideProgramiranje[i].style.display = "none";
    }
});

$('#itnBtn').click(function() {
    var divsToShowMarketing = document.getElementsByClassName("дизајн");
    for(var i = 0; i < divsToShowMarketing.length; i++){
        divsToShowMarketing[i].style.display = "block";
    }
    divsToHideItn = document.getElementsByClassName("маркетинг");
    for(var i = 0; i < divsToHideItn.length; i++){
        divsToHideItn[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    
    var divsToHideProgramiranje = document.getElementsByClassName("програмирање");
    for(var i = 0; i < divsToHideProgramiranje.length; i++){
        divsToHideProgramiranje[i].style.display = "none";
    }
});

<div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-4" style="background-color:#302f38"><input type="button" id="programiranjeBtn" value="Programiranje" class="sa" style="background-color:#302f38; color:#fcd232;"/></div>
      <div class="col-4" style="background-color:#302f38"><input type="button" id="marketingBtn" value="Marketing" class="sa" style="background-color:#302f38; color:#fcd232;" /></div>
      <div class="col-4" style="background-color:#302f38"><input type="button" id="itnBtn" value="Drugo" class="sa" style="background-color:#302f38; color:#fcd232;" /></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row nav-bg">
      <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <h1 style="color:#302f38;" class="p-5"><b>Проекти</b></h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <?php
    require 'cards.php';
    ?>
```

There are script tags where needed, i just wasnt sure how to put them all in different tags.